# Uncontinuable solution of a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the initial boundary value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y'(t) & = f(t,y(t)),\;\;t\geq t_0,\\
y(t_0) &= y_0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m.$ Let that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on a bounded domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^m.$

First of all, what means the following term : The above initial value problem has a unique uncontinuable solution for all $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^m.$ It is sufficient that the above initial value problem has a unique uncontinuable solution in view of Lipschitz continuity of $f$ on a bounded domain?

Comment: What do you mean with "uncontinuable"? The usual term is "local solution", there may be a continuation, or not. Or do you mean a maximal solution inside $D$, that is for the restriction of the ODE to $D$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann That my question. I have never seen the term "uncontinuable". Maybe is means "local solution". I have a specific f and I want to find when the IVP has "uncontinuable" solution. Therefore, it is sufficient to prove that $f$  is Lipschitz continuous on a bounded domain

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean $D \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^{m}$.
It means that for every $y_0$ and $t_0$ there exist exactly one open interval $(t_1, t_2)$ with $t_1 < t_0 < t_2$ and differentiable function $Y: (t_1, t_2) \to \mathbb R^m$ such that $Y(t_0) = y_0$, $Y'(t) = f(t, Y(t))$ for $t_1 < t < t_2$, and there is no larger open interval for which this is true.  Note that by writing $f(t,Y(t))$ we imply $(t,Y(t)) \in D$ for $t_1 < t < t_2$.

Comment: Therefore, it is sufficient to assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on a bounded domain in order to have a unique uncontinuable solution?